# Bootstrap Carousel with white background during transition from a slide to another

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-transitions, carousel

I've got a problem with my Bootstrap Carousel. The problem is the layout between one slide and another, during the transformation with css. For a second and only for a small portion of the background, it is re-applied the initial css style both to the text and to the background.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/*carousel*/
.absolute {
  margin-bottom: -46px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 250px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.index .item.active {
  height: 450px;
  background-image: url(images/first-back.jpg);
  background-position: 0 5%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.34);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.carousel-inner .item:nth-child(2) {
  background: url(images/ac-bottom.jpg);
  height: 450px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 52%;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.34);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.carousel-inner .item:nth-child(3) {
  background: url(images/grills-slider.jpg);
  height: 450px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 52%;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.34);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.carousel-inner .item:nth-child(4) {
  background: url(images/store.jpg);
  height: 450px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 52%;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.34);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.index .item:nth-child(4) h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.item.active h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 66%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <h1>Is relaxing</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>IS PEACE OF MIND</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>IS CONFIDENCE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>STARTS HERE</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

As you can notice, I'm using a background images instead of a normal  tag inside the html. Last thing, I'm using a h1 outside the carousel

```
<h1 class="absolute">COMFORT</h1>
```

Which will remain fixed, for layout purpose.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD. Avoid of using the `.active` class for decoration. This class provides a transition between slides. You can see how `.carousel-inner > .item.active` and 
`.carousel-inner > .active` are defined in the [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css).

Please check new code. Is it what you want to achieve?

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.carousel-inner {
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.carousel-inner .item {
  height: 450px;
  background-image: url(//placehold.it/600x200/69c/def/?text=first);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 52%;
  background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.34);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.carousel-inner .item:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(//placehold.it/600x200/9c6/efd/?text=second);
}
.carousel-inner .item:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(//placehold.it/600x200/c69/fde/?text=third);
}
.carousel-inner .item:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url(//placehold.it/600x200/96c/edf/?text=fourth);
}

.carousel-inner .item h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.carousel-inner .item:nth-child(4) h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <h1>Is relaxing</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>Is peace of mind</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>Is confidence</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>Starts here</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is a weird effect between two slides, it means that for a second it appears the h1 element with a white background (the h1 is without positioning so it is at the top of the page) and after few seconds it appears the right format. Do you have any clue why it does happen?

Comment: @MarcoMaffei Avoid of using the `.active` class for decoration. This class provides a transition between slides. You can see how `.carousel-inner > .item.active` and 
`.carousel-inner > .active` are defined in the [bootstrap.css](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css).

Comment: This was actually a really good suggestion.. Avoid always .active or every other bootstrap classes, right?

Comment: @MarcoMaffei When you have changed any Bootstrap class, you have changed the behavior of some Bootstrap component. You can do it if you understand the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it was because I added few other lines of code (css style) to style a module inside my code (a javascript module). This very style contains two classes (right and left) .right and .left which interfered with my style (bootstrap carousel adds the class right and left to each slide of the carousel). Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

If white space is showing up between your slides during transition you may want to try changing the Twitter Bootstrap code .carousel-inner { overflow: hidden; } to .carousel-inner { overflow: visible; }.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change from **hidden** to **visible**

```
.carousel-inner { 
    overflow: visible; 
}
```

Then add to body tag

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```